# Remote validation not working for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have made a remote validation in my project, to avoid duplicate entries in DB. My model class is like this

```
    public class Supplier
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    [Required, DisplayName("Supplier Code")]
    [Remote("ViCodeExists", "Supplier", "Vi Code is already exists.", AdditionalFields = "SupplierId")]
    public string SupplierCode { get; set; }

}
```

And inside my `SupplierController` I have the function like this

```
 public JsonResult ViCodeExists(string SupplierCode, int SupplierId = 0)
    {
        var user = _db.Suppliers.Where(x => x.SupplierCode == SupplierCode.Trim() && x.SupplierId != SupplierId);
        return !user.Any() ?
           Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) :
           Json(string.Format("{0} is already exists.", SupplierCode),
               JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In my create View

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SupplierCode)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupplierCode)
```

Everything looks okay to me, but this validation does not works. I have tried adding breakpoint inside controller, But it never get hit. Can any one point out What I am doing wrong here?

> Note: I have same type of validation in some other controllers in the
>   same project and they all work well. Issue is with this one only.

Comment: Your using the wrong overload. Change it to `[Remote("ViCodeExists", "Supplier", ErrorMessage = "Vi Code is already exists.", AdditionalFields = "SupplierId")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) of `RemoteAttribute` that accepts 3 string parameters where the 3rd parameter is the area name (not an error message).

Change the attribute to

```
[Remote("ViCodeExists", "Supplier", ErrorMessage = "Vi Code is already exists.", AdditionalFields = "SupplierId")]
public string SupplierCode { get; set; }
```

Note your overriding the error message in the methods return statement anyway, so you can probably omit it and just use

```
[Remote("ViCodeExists", "Supplier", AdditionalFields = "SupplierId")]
public string SupplierCode { get; set; }
```